# Tomcat start up error

Tags: tomcat, lifecycleexception

I am getting the following error in the Catalina log file while starting Tomcat on Windows:

```
Sep 3, 2010 3:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:531)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Sep 3, 2010 3:22:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 67604 ms
```

But when I changed the port number from `8080` to `9000` then there was no error but the request to http://localhost:9000/ gives the 404 error `The requested resource (/) is not available`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: looks like you started Tomcat when it was already running

Comment: how did you change the port, which line did you change?

Comment: On my computer is was Skype

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One application is using the 8080 port. To find out which one, use the following command on Windows Command Prompt:

```
C:\>netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:8080
```

Then take the number in the last column (that's the process ID) and find out which is the process in task manager. If nothing comes out of the command, then you have no application using that port.

Answer (score 3):

```
C:\>netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:8080
```

This had fixed it , by just clearing the process with this id from the processes and restarting TomCat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start tomcat at port 80 as root user.Other port do not.

Answer (score 0):

Another process is using that port (probably another Tomcat instance).

If you don't want to use another port for your actual Tomcat instance, you need to kill that process.

### cmd

- #### 1 line

  ```
  for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -ao ^| findstr 0.0.8080') do taskkill /pid %a
  ```

  or
- #### 2 lines

  - **get PID**

    ```
    netstat -ao | findstr 0.0:8080
    ```

    you get something like this:

    ```
    TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5180
    ```

    (the last value is the PID - use it in the following command)
  - **kill process**

    ```
    taskkill /pid <pid>
    ```

Comment: I found Tomcat itself using 8080 port. So killing that stops server. How it can be possible as tomcat occupying port then given ``org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed``.